# Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

Tags: flutter, gradle

I start learning flutter last year and created a small project which run fine, and stopped learning it until now...

so today, after update flutter to latest version (2.5.0) and start running the project again, I'm stuck with this error when trying to run it again :

```
Launching lib\order_route.dart on ASUS X01BDA in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/D:/progie/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widgets-0.1.12/lib/src/tagged_text/tagged_text.dart:295:36: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
            MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)?.textScaleFactor ??
                                   ^^^^^^
/D:/progie/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:841:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
                        ^^
/D:/progie/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widgets-0.1.12/lib/src/feature_discovery/src/overlay_widgets.dart:239:20: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/D:/progie/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
      style: theme.title.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                   ^^^^^
/D:/progie/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widgets-0.1.12/lib/src/feature_discovery/src/overlay_widgets.dart:248:20: Error: The getter 'subhead' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/D:/progie/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subhead'.
      style: theme.subhead.copyWith(color: Colors.white70),
                   ^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\progie\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\progie\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

what I already did :

- running flutter doctor, everything ok
- invalidate caches/restart
- Pub Upgrade in pubspec.yaml

but doesn't help at all

I'm using android studio version 4.1

From the error, the code is 700ish line, but I don't know which part generate the above error, and I don't even use the TextTheme or MediaQuery in the code.

running pub outdated :

```
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name  Current    Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest   

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
async         *2.8.1     *2.8.1      *2.8.1      2.8.2    
characters    *1.1.0     *1.1.0      *1.1.0      1.2.0    
csslib        *0.16.2    *0.16.2     *0.16.2     0.17.0   
html          *0.14.0+4  *0.14.0+4   *0.14.0+4   0.15.0   
matcher       *0.12.10   *0.12.10    *0.12.10    0.12.11  
quiver        *2.1.5     *2.1.5      *2.1.5      3.0.1    

transitive dev_dependencies:
test_api      *0.4.2     *0.4.2      *0.4.2      0.4.3    
all dependencies are up-to-date.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

is the problem related to the dependencies above?

any help will really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it available on GitHub?

Comment: Hi Yeasin, The project is not on GitHub, it's just a simple dart file playing with widget

if you don't mind, I uploaded the single dart file here : https://download.solisresto.com/doc/order_route.dart

Comment: Beside this dart file, there are others needed to be handled, if you can upload on GitHub, I will give a try.

Comment: I'm sorry, turn out I was already linked the project to bitbucket before. Can this work : https://bitbucket.org/k1ngm4n/laris_flutter/src/master/

the error will show when I run the order_route.dart

Comment: As per [semver](https://semver.org/) specs, to which Flutter adheres, major version bumps indicate breaking changes, which Flutter 2.x did. Most notably: [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot has happened with flutter over the past one year. You upgrading to 2.5 means your flutter projects will have null safety and you might need to update any of your dependencies to their latest versions that might support null safety. So the error is coming from the flutter widgets package. If you check https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widgets it says the package is no longer updated so it is outdated and you are advised to use one of the alternatives available.

Comment: Hi Patrick, the project was build on "flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable"

so, yeah it was long time ago.

here's the dependencies from the pubspec.yaml :

`code`
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  http: ^0.13.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  marquee: ^2.2.0
  random_string: ^2.0.1
  flutter_widgets: any

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
`code`

about the null safety, can you be more specific, where should I look into? 

Thanks for the help man

Comment: Okay so  i am going to update my answer and attach a link to explain better

Comment: hi, I updated my question above with Pub Outdated, is it possible related to the error?

Comment: Basically the flutter_widgets package is outdated. Remove it and use the alternatives listed and that should work. Updating it would not solve your issue i'm afraid

Comment: yes you are right man, after i comment out the import flutter_widgets.dart, and then points to ItemScrollController, and after i comment it, the code is running now, but it's bump into null-safety issues which is not related anymore to the the first question.

This is solving my problem. thanks man!